# System Crashed After Gpu Driver Update

Tags: updates, nvidia, crash

I have a problem with my gpu driver. I'm new in Linux World and i can't fix it. The problem is when i update gpu driver, system not responding after login screen. Please look at this image and video.

[image]

[and Video](https://streamable.com/sf9ui)

I have GeForce 7025/630a GPU and AppCenter recommend Nvidia-304 (304.135) driver. But when I install gpu driver os not responding. I m sorry for bad English by the way.

Comment: Maybe you can uninstall the driver? If you can't use the machine at all, you can get a tty terminal by typing `ctrl` + `alt` + `f1`  (you may need to hold function lock to get the f1 key) you then type your username and password to log-in to terminal - from here you can type admin commands. I don't know what commands you would need. You can return to desktop with `ctrl` + `alt` + `fn` + `f7` - or if fn lock is off it would be same but without the `fn`

Comment: Thanks for  comment  but does nt work.

Comment: If you can't even access the tty then your machine has crashed fully and you should instead hold shift on restart and try safe mode or other boot options. Take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the recovery mode and reset your system settings.
There are many reasons for this problem. You can edit the Startup menu at the grub interface `E`, enter ‘acpi=off’, and then press F10 into the system. If you can see the desktop, please uninstall the graphics driver.